# Type of data in columns of a data set

Tags: dataset

How can I get the head of the elemtns in the columns and at the same time count how many of them are they?

Here is the data set I am working with:

```
dataset=Dataset[{
  <|"speed" -> 4, "distance" -> 2.01|>,
  <|"speed" -> 4, "distance" -> 10.03|>,
  <|"speed" -> 7, "distance" -> 4.04|>,
  <|"speed" -> 7, "distance" -> 22.8|>,
  <|"speed" -> 8, "distance" -> 16.2|>,
  <|"speed" -> 16, "distance" -> 10.1|>,
  <|"speed" -> 8, "distance" -> 12.1|>,
  <|"speed" -> 9, "distance" -> 22.1|>,
  <|"speed" -> 11, "distance" -> 32.3|>,
  <|"speed" -> 6, "distance" -> 11.12|>}
 ]
```

This is what I have tried.

```
Counts[dataset[All, {"speed" -> Head}]]
```

but getting this :

[image: output]

Comment: Please show what you have you tried?  See [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html).

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) and [`Counts`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html).

With `dataset` as in the OP, then

```
dataset[Transpose /* Map[Counts], Map[Head]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Counts of pairs of Heads:

```
dataset[All, All, Head][Counts]
```

[image: Counts of pairs of Heads]

Counts of Heads for each variable:

```
dataset[All, All, Head][Transpose][All, Counts]
```

[image: Counts of Heads for each variable]

I recommend to mix up your dataset a little to see the differences between those two.

Answer (score 0):

A little inside trick you can try:

```
Dataset`GetType[dataset]
(* TypeSystem`Vector[
    TypeSystem`Struct[
       {"speed", "distance"},
       {TypeSystem`Atom[Integer], TypeSystem`Atom[Real]}
    ],
    10
  ]
*)
```

This gives you the types that `Dataset` inferred from your data.